# Force Close Java Null Exception

Tags: android

Im getting a force close error when I am trying to launch my app. Its caused by a java.lang.NullPointerException. I ahve posted the code and LogCat hopefully someone can figure it out.

```
//initialize game and surface class
public class RunfoxrunActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
private SurfacePanel game;

//saving state
public static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.kobaj.runfoxrun_prefs", 0);
    ed = mPrefs.edit();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    game = new SurfacePanel(this);
    game.onInitialize();

    // last
    setContentView(game);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    wl.release();

    game.onScreenPause(ed);
    ed.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    wl.acquire();

    game.onScreenResume(mPrefs);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    game.onScreenQuit(ed);
    ed.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME || i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH || i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        game.onUserPause();

    if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        return false;

    game.im.eventUpdateDown(i, event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int i, KeyEvent event)
{
    game.im.eventUpdateUp(i, event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    game.im.eventUpdate(e);
    return true;
}
}
```

And the LogCat is

```
    02-16 13:39:35.110: I/AudioSystem(20006): getting audio flinger
    02-16 13:39:35.120: I/AudioSystem(20006): returning new audio session id
    02-16 13:39:35.120: D/MediaPlayer(20006): reset() in
    02-16 13:39:35.130: D/MediaPlayer(20006): reset() out
    02-16 13:39:35.130: I/AudioSystem(20006): getting audio flinger
    02-16 13:39:35.130: I/AudioSystem(20006): returning new audio session id
    02-16 13:39:35.240: D/MediaPlayer(20006): start() in
    02-16 13:39:35.360: D/MediaPlayer(20006): start() out
    02-16 13:39:35.711: I/dalvikvm(20006): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.<init>
    02-16 13:39:35.711: W/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: unable to resolve static method 757: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
    02-16 13:39:35.711: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
    02-16 13:39:35.711: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0009 in Lorg/simpleframework/xml/stream/StreamProvider;.<init> ()V
    02-16 13:39:35.711: W/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
    02-16 13:39:35.711: W/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
    02-16 13:39:35.711: I/dalvikvm(20006): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
    02-16 13:39:35.711: W/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 755: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
    02-16 13:39:35.711: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    02-16 13:39:35.711: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: dead code 0x0005-000a in Lorg/simpleframework/xml/stream/StreamProvider;.provide (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lorg/simpleframework/xml/stream/EventReader;
    02-16 13:39:35.711: I/dalvikvm(20006): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
    02-16 13:39:35.721: W/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 756: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/Reader;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
    02-16 13:39:35.721: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    02-16 13:39:35.721: D/dalvikvm(20006): VFY: dead code 0x0005-000a in Lorg/simpleframework/xml/stream/StreamProvider;.provide (Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/simpleframework/xml/stream/EventReader;
    02-16 13:39:35.991: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 371K, 48% free 2979K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 36ms+44ms
    02-16 13:39:36.081: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:36.261: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 548K, 49% free 2985K/5831K, external 0K/0K, paused 90ms+2ms
    02-16 13:39:36.311: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:36.331: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_EXPLICIT freed 337K, 50% free 2939K/5831K, external 0K/0K, paused 28ms
    02-16 13:39:38.173: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:38.183: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 49% free 3027K/5831K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+5ms
    02-16 13:39:38.263: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:38.323: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 616K, 50% free 2980K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+3ms
    02-16 13:39:38.393: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:38.463: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 50% free 2997K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
    02-16 13:39:38.513: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 12
    02-16 13:39:38.594: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 513K, 50% free 2995K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+3ms
    02-16 13:39:38.644: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 12
    02-16 13:39:38.734: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 500K, 49% free 3007K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
    02-16 13:39:38.774: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 9
    02-16 13:39:38.894: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_CONCURRENT freed 508K, 49% free 3009K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
    02-16 13:39:38.924: E/JAKOBERR(20006): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'xstartpos' private int com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation.xstartpos for class com.kobaj.runfoxrun.Animation at line 12
    02-16 13:39:38.944: D/dalvikvm(20006): GC_EXPLICIT freed 240K, 51% free 2944K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 27ms
    02-16 13:39:38.964: D/AndroidRuntime(20006): Shutting down VM
    02-16 13:39:38.964: W/dalvikvm(20006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kobaj.runfoxrun/com.kobaj.runfoxrun.RunfoxrunActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at com.kobaj.runfoxrun.SurfacePanel.onInitialize(SurfacePanel.java:124)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at com.kobaj.runfoxrun.RunfoxrunActivity.onCreate(RunfoxrunActivity.java:52)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
    02-16 13:39:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20006):    ... 11 more
    02-16 13:39:40.976: D/Process(20006): killProcess, pid=20006
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:745)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:797)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:854)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:851)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: D/Process(20006): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-16 13:39:40.986: I/Process(20006): Sending signal. PID: 20006 SIG: 9
```

Comment: We need the code of your SurfacePanel, and please mark the line 124.

Comment: If you read your error stack trace carefully, you'll see that the error is thrown in the `SurfacePanel` class's `onInitialize` method.  I suggest you start investigating there.

Comment: Where did you get `XMLHandler` class? It seems `XMLHandler.readSerialFile(..)` is returning `null`?

Comment: @PeterKnego Not sure what you mean what do you need? this is the XMLHandler http://pastebin.com/DN5N3Uc2

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem parsing

```
loadingStar = XMLHandler.readSerialFile(getResources(), R.raw.star, Sprite.class);
```

thus loadingStar is null. From warnings in the log I am guessing there is something wrong with XML parser

Comment: I have the star.xml in my raw folder though soo what could the issue be?

Comment: Hard to say. Try setting a breakpoint inside readSerialFile and see what's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE happens in `SurfacePanel`, line 124. Go check there.

```
com.kobaj.runfoxrun.SurfacePanel.onInitialize(SurfacePanel.java:124)
```

Comment: Not really, should've been a comment. The real answer will be possible when the OP shows us SurfacePanel and says which line is 124.

Comment: Obviously the problem is that OP can't read logcat. Pointing where the  error is (and showing logcat line to show how to find it next time) should be sufficient to find and resolve NPE.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question why the error is thrown. A suggestion for the OP how he should improve is question should be posted as a comment as it doesn't solve the problem the OP has. That is what comments are meant for.

Comment: @PeterKnego This is the `SurfacePanel` http://pastebin.com/mSbftBm5 Line 111 on paste bin relates to line 124 in eclipse

Comment: Took a look at the code. Granted - not a trivial to know why NPE happens. My guess is `loadingStar` is null. The easiest is to set a debugger breakpoint on that line and see which reference (variable/field) is `null`: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: your getStar() probably returns null. Matt you should finally start learning how to use the debugger! It is an important skill...

Comment: @WarrenFaith not got a clue where to start with that :/

Comment: @Matt Debug tutorial for starters: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html